# Why does Jeliot not recognize string.split()?

Tags: java, string, split

My university wants us to use [Jeliot](http://cs.joensuu.fi/jeliot/) to compile our java programs. 
Does anyone know why this piece of code

```
import java.lang.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "1 4 5 8 9 6 2";
        System.out.print(s.split(" ")[0]);   
    }
}
```

works on other compilers but not Jeliot?
The error displayed is: 
"Runtime Exception 
Feature is not yet implemented." 
Is it because of a missing library?

Comment: `String.split()` has been part of the JDK since Java 1.4 so for years now. So it's not a problem with Java but seems to be a problem with Jeliot which doesn't seem a compiler but a visualazition, isn't it? Also this seems to be orphaned for a while, at least the last "news" being from 2014 doesn't build confidence. I'm not you'll find answers to such a specific problem here - but in any case you should always add the stacktrace when asking about exceptions.

Comment: Hello Thomas,
I know Jeliot is outdated and I hate using it, but my unversity forces us...
There is no stacktrace (literally nothing appears on the console), the only thing I can see is "Runtime Exception; Feature is not yet implemented." displayed on the graphic interface.